# Loading Images From URL in Android

Tags: android, image, web-services

I am Trying to get Images From Url and Text Data, But it's close the App Forcefully.What is problem in it..

```
public class BandMembers extends ListActivity {
public static final String TAG_MEMBER_NAME = "member_name";
public static final String TAG_MEMBER_SKILL = "member_skill";
public static final String TAG_THUMB_MEMBER_IMAGE = "member_thumb_image";
public static String URL = "http://...../.../..../mainAPI.php"; 

ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> memberList;
String responseData = null;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.band_members);

    memberList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String,String>>();
    new AsyncData().execute();
}

class AsyncData extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Void> {
    ProgressDialog pDialog;

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        pDialog = new ProgressDialog(BandMembers.this);
        pDialog.setTitle("Loading....");
        pDialog.setMessage("Please wait...");
        pDialog.show();
        super.onPreExecute();
    }

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(String... args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(URL);
        try {
            List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
            nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("rquest","{\"method\":\"band_members\",\"body\":[{}]}"));
            httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs, HTTP.UTF_8));
            HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
            HttpEntity resEntity = response.getEntity();
            responseData = EntityUtils.toString(resEntity);
            try {
                JSONArray data = new JSONArray(responseData);
                for (int i = 0; i < data.length(); i++) {
                    HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
                    JSONObject c = data.getJSONObject(i);
                    String memberName = c.getString(TAG_MEMBER_NAME);
                    String memberSkill = c.getString(TAG_MEMBER_SKILL);
                    String memberImage = c.getString(TAG_THUMB_MEMBER_IMAGE);
                    map.put(TAG_MEMBER_NAME, memberName);
                    map.put(TAG_MEMBER_SKILL, memberSkill);
                    map.put(TAG_THUMB_MEMBER_IMAGE, memberImage);
                    memberList.add(map);
                }

            } catch (JSONException e) {
                // TODO: handle exception
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
            Toast.makeText(BandMembers.this, "There was an issue Try again later", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Toast.makeText(BandMembers.this, "There was an IO issue Try again later", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
        return null;
    }


    protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
        super.onPostExecute(result);
        if (pDialog != null && pDialog.isShowing()) {
            pDialog.dismiss();
        }


        setListAdapter(new BandAdapter(BandMembers.this,R.layout.band_member_row_file, memberList));

    }
}
}
```

Class Band Adapter

```
public class BandAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<HashMap<String, String>>{
Context context;
ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> myList;
HashMap<String, String> myData;
int layout;
public BandAdapter(Context context, int textViewResourceId, List<HashMap<String, String>> objects) {
    super(context, textViewResourceId, objects);
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    this.context = context;
    this.myList = (ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>) objects;
    this.layout = textViewResourceId;
}


@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    View row = null;
    TextView name, info;
    ImageView image;
    LayoutInflater inflater = ((Activity) context).getLayoutInflater();
    row = inflater.inflate(layout, parent, false);
    name = (TextView)row.findViewById(R.id.textMemberName);
    info = (TextView)row.findViewById(R.id.textMemberInfo);
    myData = myList.get(position);
    try{
        image = (ImageView)row.findViewById(R.id.imageMember);
        name.setText("" + myData.get(BandMembers.TAG_MEMBER_NAME));
        info.setText("" + myData.get(BandMembers.TAG_MEMBER_SKILL));
        Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream((InputStream)new URL ("" + myData.get(BandMembers.TAG_THUMB_MEMBER_IMAGE)).getContent());
        image.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
    } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return row;
}
 }
```

and My Logcat is..

```
04-26 12:01:15.574: E/AndroidRuntime(2575): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
04-26 12:01:15.574: E/AndroidRuntime(2575): android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException
04-26 12:01:15.574: E/AndroidRuntime(2575):     at android.os.StrictMode$AndroidBlockGuardPolicy.onNetwork(StrictMode.java:1084)
04-26 12:01:15.574: E/AndroidRuntime(2575):     at java.net.InetAddress.lookupHostByName(InetAddress.java:391)
04-26 12:01:15.574: E/AndroidRuntime(2575):     at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByNameImpl(InetAddress.java:242)
04-26 12:01:15.574: E/AndroidRuntime(2575):     at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName(InetAddress.java:220)
04-26 12:01:15.574: E/AndroidRuntime(2575):     at libcore.net.http.HttpConnection.<init>(HttpConnection.java:71)
04-26 12:01:15.574: E/AndroidRuntime(2575):     at libcore.net.http.HttpConnection.<init>(HttpConnection.java:50)
04-26 12:01:15.574: E/AndroidRuntime(2575):     at libcore.net.http.HttpConnection$Address.connect(HttpConnection.java:351)
04-26 12:01:15.574: E/AndroidRuntime(2575):     at libcore.net.http.HttpConnectionPool.get(HttpConnectionPool.java:86)
04-26 12:01:15.574: E/AndroidRuntime(2575):     at libcore.net.http.HttpConnection.connect(HttpConnection.java:128)
04-26 12:01:15.574: E/AndroidRuntime(2575):     at libcore.net.http.HttpEngine.openSocketConnection(HttpEngine.java:308)
04-26 12:01:15.574: E/AndroidRuntime(2575):     at libcore.net.http.HttpEngine.connect(HttpEngine.java:303)
04-26 12:01:15.574: E/AndroidRuntime(2575):     at libcore.net.http.HttpEngine.sendSocketRequest(HttpEngine.java:282)
04-26 12:01:15.574: E/AndroidRuntime(2575):     at libcore.net.http.HttpEngine.sendRequest(HttpEngine.java:232)
04-26 12:01:15.574: E/AndroidRuntime(2575):     at libcore.net.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.connect(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:80)
04-26 12:01:15.574: E/AndroidRuntime(2575):     at java.net.URLConnection.getContent(URLConnection.java:194)
04-26 12:01:15.574: E/AndroidRuntime(2575):     at java.net.URL.getContent(URL.java:447)
04-26 12:01:15.574: E/AndroidRuntime(2575):     at com.bandapp.BandAdapter.getView(BandAdapter.java:51)
04-26 12:01:15.574: E/AndroidRuntime(2575):     at android.widget.AbsListView.obtainView(AbsListView.java:2033)
04-26 12:01:15.574: E/AndroidRuntime(2575):     at android.widget.ListView.measureHeightOfChildren(ListView.java:1244)
04-26 12:01:15.574: E/AndroidRuntime(2575):     at android.widget.ListView.onMeasure(ListView.java:1155)
04-26 12:01:15.574: E/AndroidRuntime(2575):     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:12603)
04-26 12:01:15.574: E/AndroidRuntime(2575):     at android.widget.RelativeLayout.measureChild(RelativeLayout.java:579)
04-26 12:01:15.574: E/AndroidRuntime(2575):     at android.widget.RelativeLayout.onMeasure(RelativeLayout.java:392)
04-26 12:01:15.574: E/AndroidRuntime(2575):     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:12603)
04-26 12:01:15.574: E/AndroidRuntime(2575):     at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:4677)
04-26 12:01:15.574: E/AndroidRuntime(2575):     at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:293)
04-26 12:01:15.574: E/AndroidRuntime(2575):     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:12603)
04-26 12:01:15.574: E/AndroidRuntime(2575):     at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:4677)
04-26 12:01:15.574: E/AndroidRuntime(2575):     at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1369)
04-26 12:01:15.574: E/AndroidRuntime(2575):     at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:660)
04-26 12:01:15.574: E/AndroidRuntime(2575):     at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:553)
04-26 12:01:15.574: E/AndroidRuntime(2575):     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:12603)
04-26 12:01:15.574: E/AndroidRuntime(2575):     at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:4677)
04-26 12:01:15.574: E/AndroidRuntime(2575):     at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:293)
04-26 12:01:15.574: E/AndroidRuntime(2575):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.onMeasure(PhoneWindow.java:2072)
04-26 12:01:15.574: E/AndroidRuntime(2575):     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:12603)
04-26 12:01:15.574: E/AndroidRuntime(2575):     at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:4677)
04-26 12:01:15.574: E/AndroidRuntime(2575):     at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:293)
04-26 12:01:15.574: E/AndroidRuntime(2575):     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:12603)
04-26 12:01:15.574: E/AndroidRuntime(2575):     at android.widget.RelativeLayout.measureChildHorizontal(RelativeLayout.java:594)
04-26 12:01:15.574: E/AndroidRuntime(2575):     at android.widget.RelativeLayout.onMeasure(RelativeLayout.java:376)
04-26 12:01:15.574: E/AndroidRuntime(2575):     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:12603)
04-26 12:01:15.574: E/AndroidRuntime(2575):     at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:4677)
04-26 12:01:15.574: E/AndroidRuntime(2575):     at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:293)
04-26 12:01:15.574: E/AndroidRuntime(2575):     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:12603)
04-26 12:01:15.574: E/AndroidRuntime(2575):     at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:4677)
04-26 12:01:15.574: E/AndroidRuntime(2575):     at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:293)
04-26 12:01:15.574: E/AndroidRuntime(2575):     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:12603)
04-26 12:01:15.574: E/AndroidRuntime(2575):     at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:4677)
04-26 12:01:15.574: E/AndroidRuntime(2575):     at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1369)
04-26 12:01:15.574: E/AndroidRuntime(2575):     at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:660)
04-26 12:01:15.574: E/AndroidRuntime(2575):     at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:553)
04-26 12:01:15.574: E/AndroidRuntime(2575):     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:12603)
04-26 12:01:15.574: E/AndroidRuntime(2575):     at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:4677)
04-26 12:01:15.574: E/AndroidRuntime(2575):     at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:293)
04-26 12:01:15.574: E/AndroidRuntime(2575):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.onMeasure(PhoneWindow.java:2072)
04-26 12:01:15.574: E/AndroidRuntime(2575):     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:12603)
04-26 12:01:15.574: E/AndroidRuntime(2575):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1044)
04-26 12:01:15.574: E/AndroidRuntime(2575):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.handleMessage(ViewRootImpl.java:2418)
04-26 12:01:15.574: E/AndroidRuntime(2575):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
04-26 12:01:15.574: E/AndroidRuntime(2575):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
04-26 12:01:15.574: E/AndroidRuntime(2575):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityT
```

Please Help me and give some solution with code, Thank you in Advance..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

just change BandAdapter class with this one..

```
public class BandAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<HashMap<String, String>> {
Context context;
ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> myList;
HashMap<String, String> myData;
int layout;

public BandAdapter(Context context, int textViewResourceId, List<HashMap<String, String>> objects) {
    super(context, textViewResourceId, objects);
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    this.context = context;
    this.myList = (ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>) objects;
    this.layout = textViewResourceId;
}


@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    View row = null;
    TextView name, info;
    ImageView image;
    Bitmap bimage;

    LayoutInflater inflater = ((Activity) context).getLayoutInflater();
    row = inflater.inflate(layout, parent, false);
    name = (TextView)row.findViewById(R.id.textMemberName);
    info = (TextView)row.findViewById(R.id.textMemberInfo);
    myData = myList.get(position);
    try{
        image = (ImageView)row.findViewById(R.id.imageMember);
        name.setText("" + myData.get(BandMembers.TAG_MEMBER_NAME));
        info.setText("" + myData.get(BandMembers.TAG_MEMBER_SKILL));
        String uri = ("" + myData.get(BandMembers.TAG_THUMB_MEMBER_IMAGE).replace(" ", "%20"));
        bimage=  getBitmapFromURL(uri);
        image.setImageBitmap(bimage);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return row;
}
public static Bitmap getBitmapFromURL(String src) {
    try {
        URL url = new URL(src);
        HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        connection.setDoInput(true);
        connection.connect();
        InputStream input = connection.getInputStream();
        Bitmap myBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(input);
        return myBitmap;
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return null;
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are going to download and display the image in the imageview try Smart Image View

http://loopj.com/android-smart-image-view/

it is working really good .

Comment: Thanks but can you help me for doing in ImageView.?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Android query library for lazy loading of your images, its pretty simple and straightforward, you just need to specify the url of the image and this library does all the caching and image downloading for you 
And also your exception is the network on main thread exception , you should not be doin any ui related changes in the doInBackground method
for example the code to load an image is just one line

```
//fetch and set the image from internet, cache with file and memory 
aq.id(R.id.image1).image("http://www.vikispot.com/z/images/vikispot/android-w.png");
```

You can check out aquery at (https://code.google.com/p/android-query/)

Comment: I am using AsyncTask in Class BandMember, but not using in BandAdapter class that is use to bound layout. can you give solution in my code.

Answer (score 0):

```
        Toast.makeText(BandMembers.this, "There was an issue Try again later", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

At frist Toast cannot be used in doInBackground. it is work thread. You should always handle your UI in the UI thread.

At same time,

```
Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream((InputStream)new URL ("" +    myData.get(BandMembers.TAG_THUMB_MEMBER_IMAGE)).getContent());
```

seems it is getting image from network. It should be always running in a work thread. Unless you will get the `android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException`. It is why you get the exception.

You can create the Asyntask to load the image:

```
 class ImageDownloadTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Integer, Bitmap> {
        private ImageView mView;
        ImageDownloadTask(ImageView view){
            mView = view;
        }
        @Override
        protected Bitmap doInBackground(Void... params) {
              Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream((InputStream)new URL(""
                  + myData.get(BandMembers.TAG_THUMB_MEMBER_IMAGE)).getContent());
              return bitmap;
        }


        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Bitmap result) {
           mView.setImageBitmap(result);
        }
}
```

And then new a SynckTask to load image in your `getView` Method

```
 try{
        image = (ImageView)row.findViewById(R.id.imageMember);
        name.setText("" + myData.get(BandMembers.TAG_MEMBER_NAME));
        info.setText("" + myData.get(BandMembers.TAG_MEMBER_SKILL));
        ImageDownloadTask task = new ImageDownloadTask(image);
        task.execute();
    }
```

Comment: what can I do for Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream((InputStream)new URL ("" +    myData.get(BandMembers.TAG_THUMB_MEMBER_IMAGE)).getContent());